# install ros offline

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I need to install ros fuerte on a computer without internet.
it acts as a controller for a robot and it cannot be connected to the internet.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103991/install-ros-offline/) by [akrv](https://answers.ros.org/users/8111/akrv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-11-22

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

go to ( http://packages.ubuntu.com/ ) and search for apt-offline

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2013-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3